# Count unique entries in third column given rows of two other columns are the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If the entries in rows have the same genus and value, I want to count the total number of unique ids.

```
id    genus   value
123    yadi  1010
234    yada  1230
345  yellow  1240
123    yadi  1010
234    yada  1230
345  yellow  1240
456   vroom  1010
789    yada  1230
101  yellow  1240
121    yadi  1010
141    yada  1230
123  yellow  1240
234    yadi  4550
516    yada  6547
170  yellow  2310
```

I've tried using groupby and pivot tables but am running intro trouble with incorporating this many conditionals.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'id': [123, 234, 345, 123, 234, 345, 456, 789, 101, 121, 141, 123, 234, 516, 170],
                       'genus': ['yadi', 'yada', 'yellow', 'yadi', 'yada', 'yellow', 'vroom', 'yada', 'yellow','yadi', 'yada', 'yellow','yadi', 'yada', 'yellow'],
                       'value': [1010, 1230, 1240, 1010, 1230, 1240, 1010, 1230, 1240, 1010, 1230, 1240, 4550, 6547, 2310]})

df.pivot_table(values='genus', index='value', columns='id', aggfunc=pandas.Series.nunique)
```

and

```
df.groupby('value')['genus', 'id'].nunique()
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
value   genus   count
1010    yadi    2
1010    vroom   1
1230    yada    3
1240    yellow  4
4550    yadi    1
6547    yada    1
2310    yellow  1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: simple fix `df.groupby(['value','genus']).id.nunique()
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to group by on both `genus` and `value`. Using Wen-Ben's comment and converting it to the output you wanted:

```py
df = df.groupby(['value', 'genus']).id.nunique().to_frame()

                id
value   genus   
1010    vroom   1
        yadi    2
1230    yada    3
1240    yellow  3
2310    yellow  1
4550    yadi    1
6547    yada    1

df.reset_index(drop=False).rename({'id':'count'}, axis=1)

    value   genus   count
0   1010    vroom   1
1   1010    yadi    2
2   1230    yada    3
3   1240    yellow  3
4   2310    yellow  1
5   4550    yadi    1
6   6547    yada    1
```